# How to just restore history in R?

Tags: r, history

`--save` of R command saves the workspace. But I just want the history be stored and loaded when R (command line version) is restarted. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe there's a `--flag` but you can accomplish something similar with `savehistory(file = "...")` and `loadhistory(file = "...")`.

Comment: I believe it's done automatically by default. However, you can accomplish this by using loadhistory(file = ".Rhistory") in the same home folder.